# Regarding plotting a graph in python using matplolib from the input in text file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a written a python code that generates the output in the form of text file. The numbers in the result are very small(of the order of **`10^-120`**) and are written in the scientific notation in the form 1E-120 in the output file. I wish to plot the graph using the output in the text file. How do I plot the graph?

The output is in the form like 1 '\t' 2 stored in a text file. I wish to plot a simple x y plot between the two variables.

I am asking this here since I could not find anything related to this anywhere and I am new to python. Thanks.

Comment: What type of graph? Is it a simple `(x,y)` plot? How are the coordinate pairs formatted?

Comment: Yes. That would help.

Comment: I just need to know how to import data from a file and plot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your values are a x -> y mapping (e.g. a 1D function), plotting these values is very simple. If you have your x values in the iterable (i.e. a list or an array or anything you can iterate over) `x` and your y values in the iterable `y`, the you need to import `pyplot` and do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The fact that your values are so small is not a problem. However, for the sake of the presentation you might want to rescale them by just multiplying the values by a number, say `1e120`.

EDIT: I see right now that you need to import the data. The easiest way is [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). Assuming the data is written in your file in matrix format (one column for x, one for y), you will get this data in the same format.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('path/to/file')
x,y = data[:, 0], data[:,1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The output is in the form like 1    2. How do I import the data from a text file?

Comment: I edited my answer. See if this solves your problem.

Comment: It gives an error saying couldn't convert string into float. It is because the numbers are too small as I said in the question details, that I had to print them addressing them as string in the output file. So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: can you help me in solving this?

Comment: I don't fully understand. Can you paste part of the file in your question? Even if the numbers are tiny, there should be no problem in loading them. Numpy converts the contents of the file, which are always strings, into floating points numbers.

Comment: My code writes in the file using the following line.                            fo.write("\n %e \t   %e" %(a, b); This line of code is inside the loop that is run for several times to generate output  in a text file. Is this enough?

Comment: That should be fine. Remove the first `\n` from the file and try to load the file with `np.loadtxt`. If it does not manage to load it, the file is probably corrupted. Report here the error message, if any, or the result of the instruction otherwise. Also, make sure that you point to the right file path in the function argument (if you are on Windows you might need to use ``\`` instead of `/`).